# Is there any solution to run the same query inside foreach with different variable, using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, foreach, insert

I'm running the following PHP code bellow. I have a string with seperated data (separated by ";"). I want to split this data into an array and with foreach I want to run the same INSERT sql query, changing with the array actual item only.

After I runned the code the succesfully message appearing. But as I described only one record get into the database (and only one time so if I do the same thing at the second time no more record added, also not the record before what is there in the database already too. (This is why I got so confused.)

String example: "email@email.com;email2@email2.com;"

The PHP code:

```php
      $connection = dbconnect();
      $mail_addresses = explode(";",$_POST["mailaddresslist"]);

      for($i = 0; $i < count($mail_addresses); $i++){
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tablename` (`emsd_email`, `emsd_theme`, `emsd_timerdate`) VALUES ('".$mail_addresses[$i]."','". $_POST["themes"]."','".$_POST["emailsenddate"] ."');";
        $connection->query($query);
      }

      print_note("E-mail successfully added!");
```

There is no any error message the code is running down. In the first time it create one record (just with the first item in the array), but after that the code doesn't make any effect at all. It no matters that how many times I run it does nothing. There's no more record appearing in the database.

Comment: just to make sure: I hope you don't actually use this statement in a production environment since sql injection is very easy on this one.

Comment: Of course not I use input protector functions like mysql_strip_tags and add_slashed but it does not have real effets because I echo the array inside foreach statement and it appears correctly and this is why I got sonconfused. The forech shows both item of the array (with echo) so the explode function is worked but the query runs only once and only 1 time. Interesting but I think only just me who is amatetur.

Comment: You could use a `foreach` instead of a `for` so you don't have to worry about iterators. I'd also suggest using prepared statements and parameter binding to eliminate quoting headaches.

Answer (score 0):

- I solved it. The problem was the record must have a unique id, and it must be Auto Increment. Now it works fine. :)*